# LaTeX Memoir, customizing LOT LOF and REFERENCES in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm attempting to change the way the list of tables, figures and references appear in my TOC using the memoir document class. In general, I want them to appear at the same level as parts in the TOC. Here is the catch however, the general guidelines I'm working off say that parts are to not have page numbers or the dots associated with them, but these specific entries are essentially exceptions.

I did some searching, and found that I can get the REFERENCES to appear at part level in the TOC using the following:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{
    \renewcommand{\@memb@bchap}{
        \part*{\bibname}%
        \bibmark
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}
        \prebibhook
    }
}
```

But since my style file has `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}` set generally, I haven't found a way to toggle them on for special exceptions. Any guidance would be appreciated greatly.

Here is a link to my .cls: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/8SpsLitf)

Here is a link to MWE: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/nHybv1xu)

Comment: Here is the .cls I'm using: [asuthesis.cls](https://pastebin.com/HjF3PLvq)

Comment: I had to make a minor change to the .cls: [see here](https://pastebin.com/8SpsLitf)

Comment: Here is the MWE: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/nHybv1xu) Even if the bibliography files aren't present, running the pdflatex - bibtex - pdflatex x2 dance still makes the issue clear in the PDF.

Comment: The LOF, LOT, and REFERENCES need to be set at part level, but unlike all other part level entries, need to have page numbers and the same dot styling as chapters.

Comment: I'm not at all sure how you want the ToC to look. Please show some illustration of what you want. BTW the class that you use is not `memoir` but `asuthesis` (which admittedly is based on `memoir` but makes/adds its own code).

Comment: I know that the class is based on memoir and adds some customization to certain elements (but I attempted to make the customization rather minimal). Here is a link the style manual: [https://graduate.asu.edu/format-manual](https://graduate.asu.edu/format-manual) I'm hoping to replicate the Table of contents (chapter format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asuthesis` class is based on the `memoir` class. The `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) chapter *An example thesis design* describes the code for a thesis of the fictitious **A**rchibald **S**mythe **U**niversity, where the specification for the ToC portion is suspiciously like that defined in your reference https://graduate/asu/edu/format-manual. Try the relevant portions of the code from the chapter.

Your `asuthesis.cls` is based on modifying the `memoir.cls`. In that class the `\part` and `\chapter` entries in the ToC do not have dotted leaders between the titles and page numbers; this can, of course be modified (as below).

Following your 5 Feb comment I have come up with how to do dotted lines in the ToC for chapters, etc. At the end of your `asuthesis.cls` file add:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
```

which enables dotted leaders to chapter level entries in the ToC.

I'm not as efficient as I used to be and am still working on moving the LoT and LoT entries in the ToC to the left margin. I don't know how long you will have to wait but perhaps someone else will also take up the challenge as well.

I now have a hacky answer to moving the LoT and LoF titles in the ToC to the left margin. In addition to the above add the following at the end of your `asuthesis.cls` file:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hspace{-2em}LIST OF TABLES}
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hspace{-2em}LIST OF FIGURES}
}
```

which will shift the relevant ToC entries to the left by 2em. From the point of view of your class code you could make the same changes within your code at the appropriate place instead of at the end.

(There must be a way to get LoT/LoF titles as `\part` level entries in the ToC with dotted lines but perhaps someone else will solve that one.)

Comment: I've tried this and in fact based my initial style sheet off of the `memoir` documentation. There are only two issues that I need to fix at this point - adding leader dots in the TOC for the list of figures and tables just like for chapters and sections, and the same for the appendices. At this point my skills with both LaTeX and google are failing me.

Comment: @GregoryGelfond I've updated my answer on how to get your dotted leaders in the ToC. The remaining problem will take a while (and I'm not defining "while").

Comment: @GregoryGelfond I've updated my answer which I think does all that you asked about.